# Using Media Queries vs Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

For context, I am interested in developing a responsive website or web application.

Questions:

1. Is Twitter Bootstrap a viable alternative to writing my own media queries(e.g. will I run into limitations with Twitter Bootstrap that I would avoid by writing my own code)?
2. Is the learning curve much greater for either option?
3. What breakpoints are typically found in media queries?

Answer (score 7):

Bootstrap's responsive design is based on media queries as well. In your case you have two options.

First one is to start with Bootstrap and learning how it works by reading documentation and CSS files. Plenty of examples with media queries can be found in there. Bootstrap is really developer friendly and its learning curve isn't demanding. Few hours is more than enough to start building your first RWD.

Second option is writing your own media queries from scratches and definitely that would take more time than using ready-made style sheets. You would also have to take care of testing them with all browsers you would like to support. The main advantage is you can create exactly what you need. Bootstrap gives you lot of CSS rules that you won't need. On the other hand there are plenty of useful ones.

It all depends on size of a project and time for a development. The knowledge about media queries is mandatory if you meet specific requirements. In most cases framework like Bootstrap can solve your problems but sometimes you need to add some custom code.

The most common resolutions in RWD are:

- 240x320
- 320x480
- 600x800
- 768x1024